# How to increase Card elevation when TextFormField focused?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have a simple `Card` which include a `FormTextField` and whenever the `FormTextField` is focused, the `Card` Elevation should increase.

I'm pretty much new to Flutter and I can't figure out how to increase the elevation when a `FormTextField` is focused. I already search the documentation and didn't find anything much.

Here's the Card widget

```dart
...
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 30),
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(10),
    ),
    elevation: 5,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Text tidak boleh kosong';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
...
```

---

I expect the elevation to goes up to `10` when the TextFormField is focused. How do I achieve this? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextFormField` has a property called `focusNode`. Here is an example on how it can be used.

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => new _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
  FocusNode _focusA = new FocusNode();
  FocusNode _focusB = new FocusNode();
  int _elevation = 5;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusA.addListener(_onFocusChange);
    _focusB.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }

  void _onFocusChange(){
    if (_focusA.hasFocus || _focusB.hasFocus)
      setState(() => _elevation = 10);
    else
     setState(() => _elevation = 10);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 30),
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(10),
          ),
          elevation: _elevation,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                child: TextFormField(
                  focusNode: _focusA,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                child: TextFormField(
                  focusNode: _focusB,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need call `setState` in your - `_onFocusChange()` method to reflect the same in UI

Comment: There's a weird bug when I focus the text field if there's 2 `FormTextField`, both get focused and elevated when I press any of the TextFormField which uses the same `focusNode`

Comment: @AftarFadilah updated the answer to support that scenario.